# How can I display a fieldset if an input element inside that fieldset has a value?

Tags: jquery

I have a form that needs to display a certain fieldset if **any** of the input elements inside that fieldset has a value.

The current code I have written only works if I have one input element with a value inside the fieldset, but if I have place a second input element, it does not work properly.  I am assuming I am missing a step which needs to cycle through the elements.  I am assuming I need to implement .each() somewhere.

This form will be changed from time to time by other developers, so I have to *find* inputs instead of targeting them directly.  Thank you for any help.

Example form. I would like the fieldset with the id "toggleMe" to display, because the input "cheese" has a value, even though "bread" does not, or vice-versa:

```
<form action="scratch_submit" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <fieldset id="toggleMe">
    <label for="bread">bread</label><input type="text" name="bread" value="" id="bread">
    <label for="cheese">cheese</label><input type="text" name="cheese" value="cheese is here" id="cheese">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="neverToggle">
    <label for="wine">wine</label><input type="text" name="wine" value="wine is here" id="wine">
    <label for="beer">beer</label><input type="text" name="beer" value="" id="beer">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function toggleOptions() {
    if($("#toggleMe").find('input').val()) {
      $("#toggleMe").show();
    } else {
      $("#toggleMe").hide();
    }
  }
  toggleOptions();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function toggleOptions() {
        var value = $("#toggleMe").find("input").map(function () {
            return this.value;
        }).get().join('');
        if (value) {
            $("#toggleMe").show();
        } else {
            $("#toggleMe").hide();
        }
    }
    toggleOptions();
});
```

Basically concatenate the values of all of the child inputs and check to see if the value is not empty.

---

Or something a bit more traditional (and probably faster):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function toggleOptions() {
        var populated = false
            , $inputs = $("#toggleMe").find("input")
            , i = 0;

        while (!populated && i < $inputs.length) {
            populated = !!$inputs[i].value;
            i++;
        }

        if (populated) {
            $("#toggleMe").show();
        } else {
            $("#toggleMe").hide();
        }
    }
    toggleOptions();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function toggleOptions() {      
      if ($("#toggleMe :input").filter(function() {
          return $(this).val();
    }).size() > 0) {
              $("#toggleMe").show();
    } else {
              $("#toggleMe").hide();
    }
  }
  toggleOptions();
});
```